# Streaming a big geojson with jq

Tags: bigdata, jq, geojson

I have some big geojson (see `California.geojson` has an example https://github.com/microsoft/USBuildingFootprints?tab=readme-ov-file#download-links). That I want to convert to a `.csv` (faster to import in Postgres with `\copy`). I am passing it to STDIN.

They are  `"type": "Polygon"` but for my needs this is mostly point data and I do not need the full geometry (and neither the attributes). `jq` is perfect for this task.

Sadly, some of the biggest file seems to be big to be stored in memory (the process generated a "Killed" message). I tried the `--stream` argument but I failed to understand it or the process seems to be very slow (more than 3 hours and still "running").

A sample can be produced thanks to (see at the bottom of this post to get a copy of it):

```bash
jq '.features = .features[:5]' data/Alabama.geojson > sample.geojson
```

This is working great for "smaller" geojson (< 1.4 GB):

```bash
jq '.features | map(.geometry.coordinates) | map(.[]) | map(first) | .[] | {"long": first, "lat": last} | [.long, .lat] | @csv' small.geojson
```

But I got a "Killed" message (I am assuming I am running out of memory)

Then I tried the `--stream`, I am not sure that I understand it correctly (this [post](https://subtxt.in/library-data/2016/03/28/json_stream_jq) and this [issue](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/1984) were a big help)

This is my version with --stream (lot of "hacking")

```bash
cat sample.geojson | jq --stream "fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))" | jq ' map(.geometry.coordinates) | map(.[]) | map(first) | .[] | {"long": first, "lat": last} | [.long, .lat] | @csv'
```

It works against sample.geojson but failed on a big geojson (say 'Ohio.geojson'). Any Ideas?

I also tried to write in a file but without any more success.

#### geojson sample:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -84.959634,
              32.421887
            ],
            [
              -84.95982,
              32.421889
            ],
            [
              -84.959822,
              32.421797
            ],
            [
              -84.959767,
              32.421796
            ],
            [
              -84.959767,
              32.421771
            ],
            [
              -84.959636,
              32.421769
            ],
            [
              -84.959634,
              32.421887
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "release": 2,
        "capture_dates_range": "3/26/2020-7/22/2020"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -84.959636,
              32.42095
            ],
            [
              -84.959715,
              32.42095
            ],
            [
              -84.959714,
              32.420984
            ],
            [
              -84.959816,
              32.420985
            ],
            [
              -84.959818,
              32.420849
            ],
            [
              -84.959637,
              32.420848
            ],
            [
              -84.959636,
              32.42095
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "release": 2,
        "capture_dates_range": "3/26/2020-7/22/2020"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -84.959998,
              32.235231
            ],
            [
              -84.959877,
              32.235231
            ],
            [
              -84.959877,
              32.235288
            ],
            [
              -84.959998,
              32.235288
            ],
            [
              -84.959998,
              32.235231
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "release": 1,
        "capture_dates_range": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -84.960253,
              32.422248
            ],
            [
              -84.960069,
              32.422245
            ],
            [
              -84.960067,
              32.422321
            ],
            [
              -84.960165,
              32.422323
            ],
            [
              -84.960164,
              32.422364
            ],
            [
              -84.96025,
              32.422365
            ],
            [
              -84.960253,
              32.422248
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "release": 2,
        "capture_dates_range": "3/26/2020-7/22/2020"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -84.961602,
              32.419206
            ],
            [
              -84.961599,
              32.419354
            ],
            [
              -84.961707,
              32.419355
            ],
            [
              -84.961708,
              32.419291
            ],
            [
              -84.961794,
              32.419292
            ],
            [
              -84.961796,
              32.419208
            ],
            [
              -84.961602,
              32.419206
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "release": 2,
        "capture_dates_range": "3/26/2020-7/22/2020"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of superfluous `map`s. I think you should be able to simplify it to just `.features.[].geometry.coordinates.[].[] | @csv`

Comment: @Bergi Translate `map(first)` to `.[0]`. Then it's `.features[].geometry.coordinates[][0] | @csv`

Comment: @pmf oh right I had missed that `coordinates` is a nested array (of tuples). Should be `.coordinates.[0].[]` though, no?

Comment: thanks! yes polygon need sometimes to be multipolygon (not in this data set) ... I am testing your suggestions

Comment: `.features[].geometry.coordinates.[].[0] | @csv` is giving me the first node of every polygon which what I wanted (I randomly pick the first, but the first 3 should also be safe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original filter can be simplified as follows:

- `.features` remains as-is
- `map(.geometry.coordinates) | map(.[]) | map(first)` is actually just `map(.geometry.coordinates | .[] | first)`
- `map(…) | .[]` can then be reduced to `.[] | …`
- `{"long": first, "lat": last} | [.long, .lat]` builds an object, and immediately turns it into an array. This can be simplified to `[first,last]`, but as the array only had two items to begin with, this part actually just returns the input, and can be dropped entirely
- `@csv` remains as-is

In summary, with further contractions like `.[] | first` to `.[][0]`, you can achieve the same using

```bash
.features[].geometry.coordinates[][0] | @csv
```

This goes five levels deep, then picks the first item, and turns it into a CSV output. So, this can be translated to a `--stream` version as folloews:

```bash
fromstream(5|truncate_stream(inputs))[0] | @csv
```

```
-114.127454,34.265674
-114.127694,34.260939
-114.127988,34.264977
-114.129007,34.260229
-114.129611,34.261105
-114.130311,34.263922
-114.131834,34.284069
-114.132183,34.28509
-114.132634,34.281492
-114.133764,34.282816
:
```

Comment: You're welcome. Re "I randomly pick the first, but the first 3 should also be safe": To get the first 3 items, slice the array accordingly, then iterate over its items: `fromstream(…)[:3][] | @csv`